# python tkinter, is it possible to bind more than one function into a <Bind>?

Tags: python, tkinter

i tried different things, but nothing happens with the second one (`self.navi_enter` and `self.navi_leave`. I want in my `<Bind>` two function. the first one works but the second one doesn't. (second function works, i tested it on other buttons)

```
        self.menu_button.bind("<Enter>", self.mouse_MenuE, self.navi_enter)
        self.menu_button.bind("<Leave>", self.mouse_MenuL, self.navi_leave)
```

is it possible, to bind more than one function? (i don't get any errors)

Comment: `self.menu_button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event:[self.mouse_MenuE(), self.navi_enter()])`

Comment: ok thx a lot ! so it works now : ```self.menu_button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event:(self.mouse_MenuE(event), self.navi_enter(event)))```.

Comment: An arguably better solution is to create your own function, and have that function call the two functions.